# How to delete None Type object in App Engine datastore using Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gql

```
qObj = Group.all().fetch(Group.all().count())
for g in qObj:
   self.response.out.write(g.group)
```

I have as an output all value I have put and one value: "None" which is one of NoneType object. I want to delete this entity. When I try this code:

```
qResult = Group.gql( 'WHERE group=:1', g).get()
db.delete(qResult)
```

I am getting error: "BadArgumentError".
The question is why do I have this entity in my datastore if I most likely did not add it. How to delete this entity?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell without seeing your code in full context, but assuming that your delete action is within the iterator the problem is actually within this statement:

```
qResult = Group.gql( 'WHERE group=:1', g).get()
```

Your variable 'g' is a Group entity/object and so isn't appropriate as a filter on 'group' which is a string attribute, hence no result being returned.  This would work:

```
qResult = Group.gql( 'WHERE __key__=:1', g.key()).get()
```

But it's not actually necessary to query that entity individually (again, assuming you are iterating on the initial result set).  You can delete it directly:

```
g.delete()
```

You may want to reconsider renaming your entity attribute, since it may be confusing the issue.  Maybe something like this:

```
class Group(db.Model):
    group_name = db.StringProperty()
```

Answer (score 0):

The return of None doesn't actually represent an entity in the database; it means that your query did not return any results. Therefore, there is nothing to delete from the database.

Without anything else to go on, I'd venture to guess that your datastore doesn't actually contain any entities of the type that you think are there.

By the way, your initial query `qObj = Group.all().fetch(Group.all().count())` is hugely inefficient in that it will retrieve all of the `Group` entities twice. The `count()` operator  actually gets all of the entities in order to count them. It's much more advisable to maintain a counter programmatically.

Comment: Quote " it means that your query did not return any results".  I am getting some results (I put there before) and the last one is NoneType object. Why this "Group.all()" returns extra NoneType object at the end?

Comment: Actually, the return value isn't None; the `.group` property on one of the return values is None. I'm guessing the root of the problem is what Kevin P suggests. Thanks for making the point about the anti-pattern in the first line, though.